# Duplicate records when distinct on case-determined field

Tags: sql, sql-server

My SP returns a BIT column depending on wheter a parameter equals to another table field.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
table.[f1],
table.[f2],
--Many more fields
CASE WHEN table.MyField = @param THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS col
--Where condition not relevant
```

Said column is in a large `DISTINCT` statement. Whenever the column is true, it gets "distincted" and duplicates the record, while I need only one: true if match, otherwise false.

This is how it's returning:

```
f1   f2   flag
FOO  BAR  0
FOO  CAR  0
GOO  BAR  1
GOO  BAR  0
```

I need this:

```
f1   f2   flag
FOO  BAR  0
FOO  CAR  0
GOO  BAR  1
```

I tried using a subquery inside the `CASE` block, and pulling the generated column outside of the distinct. First option gave me wrong result set, and the second doesn't aggregate.
Last try I wrapped everything in another `SELECT` and used a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT
table.[f1],
table.[f2],
CASE WHEN table.MyField = @param THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS col
) AS t GROUP BY f1, f2
```

After playing with it for a while, It either gave me the same result or an error on the fields to aggregate.
Adding a where condition gives me all kinds of wrong result sets.

Comment: Put the `CASE` clause in an outer query. `DISTINCT` applies to all row values, including those generated by expressions

Comment: You have fundamentally different rows, you will need to aggregate them.

Comment: `Max` was what eluded me the most. I ended up using Eterm solution because it's more in line with how the rest of the SP is written, but Panagiotis is probably the more readable one. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you posted shows you want the *maximum* flag value for those field combinations, not just distinct rows. You can use `GROUP BY` for this:

```
SELECT f1,f2, MAX(IIF(MyField=@param,1,0)) as Flag
FROM Table1
GROUP BY f1,f2
```

`DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` work in similar ways, but `DISTINCT` applies to all column values, even those calculated by an expression.